# Script for saving top wallpapers from wallbase.cc into a directory

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am newish to Python and I am looking for some extra eyes on a script I wrote. I wrote this script to learn more about web-scraping and using requests and Beautiful Soup. I use it to connect to the website wallbase.cc and save the top 32 wallpapers from the last 3 days into a directory where I later cycle through displaying them on my desktop.

I'm really looking for some best practices suggestions, whatever you think is appropriate.  I'm open to any constructive criticism.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import requests
import sys
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import hashlib

def get_pic(number_imgs, timespan):
    """Returns a list of the specified number of top images over the specified
    timeframe from wallbase.cc
    """
    url = "http://wallbase.cc/toplist"
    opts = {
        'section':'wallpapers', 'q':'', 'res_opt':'gteq', 
        'res':'1920x1080', 'aspect':'1.77', 'purity':'100', 
        'board':'21', 'thpp':number_imgs, 'ts':timespan
    }
    htmltext = requests.get(url, params = opts)
    page_urls = []
    img_urls = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext.content)
    results = soup.findAll("a")

    for r in results:
        if "http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/" in r['href']:
            page_urls.append(r['href'])

    for p in page_urls:
        wp_page = requests.get(p)
        wp_soup = BeautifulSoup(wp_page.content)
        wp_results = wp_soup.findAll("img")
        for res in wp_results:
            if "http://wallpapers.wallbase.cc/" in res['src']:
                img_urls.append(res['src'])

    return img_urls

def save_pic(url):
    """Saves a file to disk when given a URL"""
    save_path = sys.argv[1]
    hs = hashlib.md5(url.encode('UTF-8')).hexdigest()
    file_ext = url.split(".")[-1]
    to_save = (save_path + hs + "." + file_ext)
    if to_save != "":
        if os.path.isfile(to_save):
            print(hs + "." + str(file_ext) + "\texists, skipping...")
        else:
            print(hs + "." + str(file_ext) + "\tdownloading...")
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, to_save)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for img in get_pic(32, "3d"):
        save_pic(img)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is nice, well documented, properly formatted and easy to understand so I won't have to much to say.

- You can have a read at [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as your code is not exactly perfect for details like spacing (you should have whitespaces after `:` in your dicts, you shouldn't have trailing whitespaces at the end of the line, etc). You'll find cool tools to check stuff for you automatically : `pep8`, `pylint`, `pyflakes`, `pychecker`.
- In `save_pic`, there is no way `to_save != ""` can be false. Indeed, because of the way you build `to_save`, I know for sure that it will contain a "." making it a non-empty string. If you want to be sure that the property keeps being True, you can use `assert` like this : `assert to_save != ""`. Otherwise, you can just get rid of the test.
- The fact that you are calling `str()` on `file_ext` in `save_pic` is a bit confusing : if this wasn't to behave like a string in the first place, I assume `to_save = (save_path + hs + "." + file_ext)` would fail.
- `save_pic` as a function probably shouldn't rely on `sys.argv[1]` : I think it would be much better if this information was to be provided as a parameter. Also, to join filename, you can use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).
- in `save_pic` (again), I think you should store the value of `hs + "." + file_ext` in a variable instead of repeating this in 3 different places. Also, you do not need parenthesis when assigning to `to_save`.
- in `get_pic`, you could use list comprehension to define page_urls : `page_urls = [r['href'] for r in soup.findAll("a") if "http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/" in r['href']]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I was able to integrate all of your recommendations. I didn't know there were tools to check pep8 compliance, I am going to look into that for sure.